# srcheadings shows only the header

Tags: header-footer

I'm trying to include a header/footer in my document with the `srcpage2` package.
The header works just fine, but the footer is not visible on any page.

```
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,ilines]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
% Header\Footer at chapter beginnings
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings} 
% Header Font
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont}
% Header
\ihead{\textit{\headmark}}
\chead{}
\ohead{}
\setlength{\headheight}{21mm} % Höhe der Kopfzeile
\setheadwidth[0pt]{\textwidth}
\setheadsepline[text]{0.4pt} % Trennlinie unter Kopfzeile
% Footer
\ifoot{}
\cfoot{}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
```

Why does it not show the footer?

Edit: I found the line that causes the issue:

```
\usepackage[left=3.0cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
```

How can I adjust the footer so the pagenumber is still visible with the values above for the border?
It works fine if I set bottom=XX to anything above 3.5

Comment: Where does `\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}`comes from? I mean the definition of `\chapterpagestyle` is miising.  Please complete your code snippet to a **compilable** minimal working example!

Comment: `\chapterpagestyle` is defined by the KOMA-Script classes `scrreprt` and `scrbook`. Maybe the footer is outside the page.

Comment: I edited the question, found the line causing the error.

Answer (score 3):

Do not change `\headheight` manually after setting the margins by `geometry`. So remove the line `\setlength{\headheight}{21mm}` or use it before `geometry`. But I would suggest to use

```
\usepackage[left=3.0cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm
 ,headheight=21mm
]{geometry}
```

BTW `headheight` should really be larger than `top`? Or do you want to use the geometry option `includehead`? With this option the header is not part of the `top` margin.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm
  ,headheight=21mm
  %,includehead
]{geometry}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\itshape}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage{showframe}% show the page layout
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I have removed `\setheadwidth` etc. because you are using the defaults.

---

Note that `scrpage2` has a successor: `scrlayer-scrpage` and it is recommended to use the new package.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm
  ,headheight=21mm
  %,includehead
]{geometry}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\itshape}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage{showframe}% show the page layou
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

or with `includehead`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, just commenting out `\setlength{\headheight}{21mm}` works fine.

Comment: Thanks for `\usepackage{showframe}`!